# No more graphical session after `apt upgrade`

Tags: debian, window-manager

I tried to update my Debian 8 system using

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Afterwards my system didn't start the graphical environment (KDE) anymore. I already tried the standard commands `apt-get clean`, `apt-get install --fix-broken` ...

```
/etc/init.d/kdm stop
/etc/init.d/kdm start
```

also shows no errors.

Looking for errors gives me:

```
grep \(EE\) /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   146.464] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   146.464] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   146.464] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   146.464] (EE) No devices detected.
[   146.464] (EE) 
[   146.464] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   146.464] (EE) 
[   146.464] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   146.464] (EE)
```

---

As pointed out by @Kevin Lemaire:

```
lspci| grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

The NVIDIA packages that got updated according to `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Upgrade:   nvidia-alternative:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1),  libegl1-nvidia:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-driver:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-opencl-common:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-glx:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-opencl-icd:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), libnvidia-compiler:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), libgl1-nvidia-glx:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-kernel-dkms:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), libnvidia-ml1:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-driver-bin:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), nvidia-smi:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1), libnvidia-eglcore:amd64 (340.102-1, 340.106-1)
```

(I filtered only the the packages containing the word `nvidia`).

**Update**
I removed the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file which seemed to fix the problem. The graphical environment could be started again. However it sometimes slows down now, and it is not possible anymore to use the second monitor. 
The VGA information changed

```
❯ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 630 OEM] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia gpu? I sometimes see similar issues on Linux with kmod-nvidia but no Nvidia gpu. What's the output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: You seem to be on the right track: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)`.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1555264

Comment: It seems I have to update this post. After removing `/etc/X1/xorg.conf` the output of `lspci` changed: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 630 OEM] (rev a1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have nvidia driver installed but actually no nvidia card.

To find out which packages are installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

To remove package found:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-package-name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. However, I am not completely sure yet if this is the right answer. I am a bit confused, as I installed no new NVIDIA packages, I only updated old ones. According to the `/var/log/apt/history.log`. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Kevin Lemaire](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/195932/kevin-lemaire) pointed out, the problem is that there is actually no NVIDIA GPU.
However, after the update `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` specified a NVIDIA GPU. Removing the file `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cli mode

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo "nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, you should be back to operational with the nouveau driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Refer [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-nvidia_and_reinstall_-nouveau_from_scratch)